# Vue.js clearing data after if is evaluated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am making a multi-step form in Rails 5 with Vue.js. I noticed that when a v-if is re-evaluated, the text in the input field gets cleared out. Is there a way to persist the info through the form steps and through other v-if evaluations?

Here's what my form looks like:

```
<fieldset class="listing-step" v-if="activeStep === 0">
  <h2>Basics</h2>

  <input type='button' value="Next" name='next' @click="activeStep++" :disabled="activeStep === stepList.length - 1" class="btn btn-secondary" />

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <strong><%= f.label :name %></strong><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="listing-step" v-if="activeStep === 1">
  <h2>Location</h2>

  <input type='button' value="Previous" name='prev' @click="activeStep--" :disabled="activeStep === 0"  class="btn btn-secondary" />
  <input type='button' value="Next" name='next' @click="activeStep++" :disabled="activeStep === stepList.length - 1"  class="btn btn-secondary" />


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="map_search" id="map_search_address" value="address" v-on:click="by_address = true" checked>
          Set by address
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="map_search" id="map_search_coords" value="coords" v-on:click="by_address = false">
          Set by coordinates
        </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="listing-location">
    <transition name="fade">
      <fieldset id="listing-location-child" name="address" v-if="by_address">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= f.label :city %></strong><br>
              <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control', 'v-bind:readonly': '!by_address' %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= f.label :state %></strong><br>
              <%= f.text_field :state, class: 'form-control', 'v-bind:readonly': '!by_address' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= f.label :address %></strong><br>
              <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control', 'v-bind:readonly': '!by_address' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </transition>

    <transition name="fade">
      <fieldset id="listing-location-child" name="coords" v-if="!by_address">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= f.label :lat, 'Latitude' %></strong><br>
              <%= f.number_field :lat, in: -90.0..90.0, step: :any, class: 'form-control', 'v-bind:readonly': 'by_address' %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
              <strong><%= f.label :lng, 'Longitude' %></strong><br>
              <%= f.number_field :lng, in: -180.0..180.0, step: :any, class: 'form-control', 'v-bind:readonly': 'by_address' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </transition>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="listing-step" v-if="activeStep === 2">
  <h2>Amenities</h2>

  <input type='button' value="Previous" name='prev' @click="activeStep--" :disabled="activeStep === 0"  class="btn btn-secondary" />
  <input type='button' value="Next" name='next' @click="activeStep++" :disabled="activeStep === stepList.length - 1"  class="btn btn-secondary" />

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Amenities</strong><br>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="listing-step" v-if="activeStep === 3">
  <h2>Images</h2>

  <input type='button' value="Previous" name='prev' @click="activeStep--" :disabled="activeStep === 0"  class="btn btn-secondary" />

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Images</strong><br>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

and my Vue initialization:

```
const progress = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-listing',
  data: {
    activeStep: 0,
    by_address: true,
    stepList: [
      {id: 0, text: 'Basics'},
      {id: 1, text: 'Location'},
      {id: 2, text: 'Amenities'},
      {id: 3, text: 'Images'}
    ]
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change v-if to v-show OR preserve the input value in `Data()` and add v-model directive to every input field. So when the `v-if`ed control gets rendered again the v-model value will change its html value

Answer (score 2):

You need to change v-if to v-show.

> v-if is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event
> listeners and child components inside the conditional block are
> properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.
>
> v-if is also lazy: if the condition is false on initial render, it
> will not do anything - the conditional block won’t be rendered until
> the condition becomes true for the first time.
>
> In comparison, v-show is much simpler - the element is always rendered
> regardless of initial condition, with just simple CSS-based toggling.
>
> Generally speaking, v-if has higher toggle costs while v-show has
> higher initial render costs. So prefer v-show if you need to toggle
> something very often, and prefer v-if if the condition is unlikely to
> change at runtime.

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show)

Comment: Using v-show somehow breaks the step functionality (i.e. when I click the Next button the next step just disappears.) v-if handles stepping through the form but clears out the data in the form :-/